# Looking for visualizations in probability and statistics

Tags: references, descriptive-statistics, data-visualization

Are there any online resources or books where probability and statistics concepts are explained in schematic pictures and plots? What I am looking for is: let's say while explaining marginal, a 2d distribution is drawn as a density plot and then summing over one variable is shown (Similarly for other concepts) Not entirely sure if this description is making sense, but recently went to a workshop where some slides of this type were shown, and they were quite useful for mental visualization.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you are new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. Maybe this website would be helpful: [Seeing Theory](https://students.brown.edu/seeing-theory/)

Comment: Do you mean "online ... besides this site"? :-)

Comment: :P . This is very useful site of course, but i am trying to see something visually. I think this is a side effect of reading Larry Wasserman's book. :)

Comment: @whuber Oh okay, now i saw some of your top answers. that explains your comment. :)